# Pass data-product object to controller.js

Tags: apex, lightning-aura-components, lightning, lightning-apps, lightning-experience

I got the following to work for a productId but I'd like to take everything  in the object, instead of:

**Component:**

```
<button type="button" data-productid="{!product.ProductId}">Get Product Id</button>
```

**Controller:**

```
var productId = event.target.dataset.productid
```

I'd like to do:

**Component:**

```
<button type="button" data-product="{!product}">Get Product Data</button>
```

**Controller:**

```
var btnData = event.target.dataset.product;
```

But I keep getting `[object Object]`

Is it possible to pass the entire object? Or would i need to do it in parts:

```
<button type="button" data-productId="{!product.ProductId}" data-productcode="{!product.ProductCode}"  data-productname="{!product.ProductName}">Get Individual data pieces</button>
```

When a user clicks the button I want to store the entire product object into a local array for use with a cart.

```
<aura:attribute name="oCart" type="Object[]" />

var btnData = event.target.dataset.product;
oCart.push({'Product':btnData});
```

Comment: Have you tried involving serialization? For example using `JSON.stringify` on the `Javascript` side or `JSON.serialize` on the server side?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Storing object in a HTML attribute, will not work because at the end you'll be getting toString() version of the Object which is nothing but `[object Object]`.

Here's an simple example:

**HTML:**

```
<div id="test" data-record="">
    hello
</div>
```

**Script:**

```
var div = document.getElementById("test");
div.setAttribute("data-record",{'name':'Praveen'});
console.log(div.getAttribute("data-record")); // returns [object Object]
```

Looks like products are being iterated using `aura:iteration` in your component. If that's the case, the you could store the index of the product being iterated in a data-* attribute (say data-index) using `indexVar`, get hold the position/index of the product object being dealt.

**markup:**

```
<aura:iteration items="{!v.products}" var="product" indexVar="index">>
    {!product.Name}
    <button type="button" data-index="{!index}" onclick="{!c.addToCart}">Get Product Data</button>
</aura:iteration
```

**controller method:**

```
addToCart : function(cmo,event,helper){
    var prodIndex = event.target.getAttribute("data-index");
    var oCart = cmp.get("v.oCart");
    oCart.push(cmp.get("v.products")[prodIndex]);
}
```

Comment: Brilliant, thank you! I had to add one more line to get it to work: `component.set("v.oCart", oCart);`